# control flow of eval()

Tags: javascript, eval

Say you're passing the following code to `eval()`

```
function async(cb) {
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        console.log('hello'); 
        cb();
    },50)
}

async(function(){
    console.log('goodbye')
})
```

and this would be the code segment using `eval()`

```
console.log('start')

try {
   var output = eval(code_from_above)
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e.message)
}

console.log('end')
```

The final console output would be:

```
start
end
hello
goodbye
```

Is there a way to add an event listener to the eval statement, which would fire as soon as the async code has completed? This would result in the following console output?

```
start
hello
goodbye
end
```

Comment: Why are you using `eval`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no Javascript event handler for a function call completing. But you can just move the `console.log('end');` to the end of the `setTimeout` function:

```
function async(cb) {
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        console.log('hello'); 
        cb();
        console.log('end');
    },50);
}

async(function(){
    console.log('goodbye');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use promises.

```js
var code_from_above = `
function async() {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 50))
  .then(() => console.log('hello'));
}
async().then(() => console.log('goodbye'))`;

console.log('start')
try {
  var output = eval(code_from_above);
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e.message);
}
output.then(() => console.log('end'));
```